# Too many nested views/persistent user-defined functions or possible circular reference of views/persistent user-defined functions referenced in query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am facing this below error when a number of queries are executed for a view with self joins

`Too many nested views/persistent user-defined functions or possible circular reference of views/persistent user-defined functions referenced in query. Only 16 levels of nested views/persistent user-defined functions are allowed.`

Any Idea what is the real reason behind this.